# How do I find out the state a jQM button is in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

A simple question. How can I find out in what state a jquery mobile button is in?
the docs have no method for that.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a button widget is disabled, its `disabled` option will be set to `true`, so you can write:

```
var isButtonDisabled = $("#yourButton").button("option", "disabled");
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for this. Seems to work. Should have seen how this one works. Sometimes you just have to ask to get your brain out of a twist.

Answer (score 0):

Active/Non active:

```
if($('#button-test').hasClass('ui-btn-active')) {
    alert('Active');    
} else {
    alert('Not active');
}
```

Enabled/Disabled

```
if($('#button-test').hasClass('ui-state-disabled')) {
    alert('Disabled');    
} else {
    alert('Enabled');
}
```

Comment: I believe the `ui-disabled` class is applied to the widget's button, not to the augmented element. You would have to write something like `$("#button-test").data("mobile-button").button.hasClass("ui-disabled")`.

Comment: No matter do you use a, input or div class ui-btn-active and  ui-disabled will always be on a main tag (no matter for markup enhancement)

Comment: Take a look at the `enable()` and `disable()` methods in the source code [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/forms/button.js). You will notice `ui-disabled` is applied to `this.button`, not `this.element`.

Comment: Every possible element in jQM can be a button as long as it has an attribute data-role="button". Your method will successfully work only on BUTTON and INPUT elements, but will fail on buttons created with data-role="button" http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LT6QC/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. The `ui-disabled` class is exposed by your `<div>` because you put it in the markup in the first place. If you omit that attribute but call `disable()` on the widget, then the class will not be applied to the `<div>` ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LT6QC/2/)). Note in passing that your fiddle says `TypeError: $.mobile is undefined` on my browser, so there may be something amiss in there.

Comment: My mistake, I have used a wrong class name, but my method still correctly detects disabled INPUT, BUTTON, A, DIV ...  buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LT6QC/4/. Look I am not saying your method is wrong, unfortunately it will not cover all button elements.